# DELETE request not allowed using CORS for cross domain request with angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, cors, cross-domain

I've created a site based on the demo of http://bitoftech.net/

I've gotten everything to work just fine, however, for some reason requests other than POST or GET get blocked when the OPTION request is made to my api.

I get the following error for the below request:

http://localhost:26264/api/photo/facebook_reactions-02.png

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:26264/api/photo/facebook_reactions-02.png. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:32150' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404
```

I receive the above error when the following code is executed:

```
'remove': { method: 'DELETE', url: serviceBase + 'api/photo/:fileName', params: { name: '@fileName' } }
```

The localhost is the correct one. If I do a post that contains data I can get through. E.g. when I want to update user data through a POST.

The demo app also contains an interceptor authInterceptorService.js so that my requests get handled before it's send.

```
var _request = function (config) {

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return config;
```

But when I look at the request:

```
OPTIONS /api/photo/facebook_reactions-02.png HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:26264
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Origin: http://localhost:32150
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:32150/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
```

I don't see the content-type separately nor as part of Access-Control-Request-Headers.
The strange thing is, in the response I see the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, TOKEN
```

So I'd think my request gets through. But, it doesn't...

For completeness sake my StartUp.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(AngularJSAuthentication.API.Startup))]

[...]

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AuthContext, Migrations.Configuration>());

    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions() {

            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
    }
```

And the web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, TOKEN" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

What am I overlooking to allow DELETE (as well as PUT) requests to get through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found!

When trying to do an OPTIONS/a DELETE request with a string that ends with an extension, such as an image, like the following request:

http://localhost:26264/api/photo/facebook_reactions-02.png

It is not allowed to do so because it can't map it to the web api controller method which is

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{fileName}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(string fileName)
```

I presume this is because the logic thinks I want to request an image.

To bypass this I changed the dot to a dash and in my code do a replace like so:

```
        var lastDashPosition = fileName.LastIndexOf('-');

        var fileNameSegment = fileName.Substring(0, lastDashPosition);
        var extensionSegment = fileName.Substring(lastDashPosition+1);

        fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", fileNameSegment, extensionSegment);
```

Following the above I handle the file as per usual:

```
        if (!photoManager.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var result = await photoManager.Delete(fileName);

        if (result.Successful)
        {
            return Ok(
                new {
                        message = result.Message
                    }
                );
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Message);
        }
```

The above works like a charm and since you need to be authorized to execute the delete and it's an image I wish to delete I can safely presume that the final dish of the string is the dash I must replace with a dot.